# Flex search field won't respond to min/max-width

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

I have a text input field in my recreation of the Google homepage.  I'm using a flexbox for everything on the line with the search field, and I'm trying to give the search bar a minimum width and a maximum width when resizing the page, but I cannot for the life of me make it responsive—it always defaults to the min- or max-width and stays that way regardless of how narrow the window is.

Here's the search bar part of my HTML:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
<link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <form id="search-wrapper" name="search-form">
    <div id="searchbar">
      <span class="material-icons-outlined">search</span>
      <input id="search-field">
      <a href="#">
        <img id="search-microphone" src="images/search_mic.png" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
  </form>
```

And the CSS:

```
:root {
    font-size: 10px;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

#search-wrapper {
    margin: 10rem auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
#searchbar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 70rem;
    min-width: 10rem;
    border: .1rem solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    border-radius: 3rem;
    margin: 0 2rem;
    padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
    font-family: "Material Icons";
    font-size: 1.8em;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
#search-field {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 1.5rem;
    border: none;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#search-microphone {
    width: 2.2rem;
    height: 2.2rem;
}
```

And if it helps, [here's a CodePen](https://codepen.io/cutlersheridan/pen/mdWKGJe?editors=1100) with a little more.

I've been scouring StackOverflow looking at questions that seem like duplicates, but have thus far been unable to find a solution that works.  I have tried every combination of `width`, `min-width`, and `max-width` I can think of between the container and input field child, such as:

- setting `max-width: 70rem` on the container, then `width: 100%` and `min-width: 40rem` on the child
- setting `max-width: 70rem` on the container, then just `min-width: 40rem` on the child
- setting `width: 70rem` and `min-width: 40rem` on the container, then `width: 100%` on the child (as well as the opposite with `max-width`)
- setting `max-width: 70rem` and `min-width: 40rem` on the container, then `width: 100%` on the child
- setting no width on the container, then `min-width: 40rem` and `max-width: 70rem` on the child
- setting no width on the container, then `width: 70rem` and `min-width: 40rem` on the child (as well the opposite with `max-width`)
- setting `min-width: 40rem` and `max-width: 70rem` on the parent, then setting the child to `flex: 1` and the other two children in the container to `flex: 0`
- setting the child to `display: block` and playing around with various combinations listed above

No matter what I try, the search field always displays at either 70rem or 40rem and does not grow or shrink at all.  I usually have no trouble making flex stuff responsive; can anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tried using media queries ? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Media queries won't accomplish what I'm looking for:  I'm trying to make the search bar's width responsively grow and shrink as the page gets wider/more narrow, I don't want the width to jump between two pre-determined options.

Comment: have you tried setting the #searchbar width to 100% and place the min&max width on #searchbar too ?

Comment: You beautiful human, thank you so much.  HOURS of my day wasted on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Hilal Arsa's comment for steering me in the direction that finally solved it.

Including `width: 100%` on `#search-wrapper`, `#searchbar`, and `#search-field` PLUS `min-width: 40rem` and `max-width: 70rem` on `#searchbar` is what finally did it:

```
#search-wrapper {
    margin: 10rem auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;                    /* added this */
}
#searchbar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;                    /* here */
    min-width: 40rem;               /* here */
    max-width: 60rem;               /* here */
    border: .1rem solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    border-radius: 3rem;
    margin: 0 2rem;
    padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
    font-family: "Material Icons";
    font-size: 1.8em;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
#search-field {
    width: 100%;                    /* and here */
    margin: 0 1.5rem;
    border: none;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, because you are using a http link to connect the css it overlays with your personal stylesheet.
I had similar issue few weeks ago and a simple solution solve my problem.
So, on the place that you think that your code can't be read(in your case the width), simply add
!important;
After the styling.

So in example:

#searchbar {

```
width: 70rem important! ;
```

}

Comment: The http link is actually just for the font that includes the magnifying glass icon, the rest of the CSS is linked the normal way as files in the same directory.  I'll update the code in my post to show that.

Comment: I just saw, why are you not using @media queries to make your job easier and add more specific breakpoints?

Comment: Specifically because it's a practice project to recreate Google's homepage and their search bar's width is responsive.  But beyond that it's common for websites to have responsive-width search fields (like this one!), I get the sense I'm missing an easy way to make it work.